# How to NppFTP with SSH key?

Tags: ssh, notepad++, sftp

I created a profile with the next options

Connection:

- Hostname: ftp.example.com
- Connection Type: SFTP
- Port: 22
- Username: wwwexample
- Password: ******
- Ask for password: no

---

Authentication:

- Try private key file authentication: yes
- Try password key authentication: no
- Try keyboard interactive authentication: no
- Private key file: D:\WORK\EXAMPLE\KEYS\wwwexample.ppk
- Passphrase: ************
- Ask every time: no

---

When I try to connect, NppFTP just says connecting and then disconnected. I created the private key with Puttygen, the same key I use for Fillezilla with Pageant (which works).

Comment: Speculative idea: Maybe use PuTTYGen to convert that PPK file to the more widely-supported OpenSSH key format?

Comment: You are right, I did what you said and it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stolen from a comment by @TOOGAM

"Use PuTTYGen to convert that PPK file to the more widely-supported OpenSSH key format."

1. Open the current SSH private key in PuTTYGen
2. File menu "Conversion"
3. Convert to OpenSSH (first option)
4. Done.

Comment: annoying that it doesn't use ssh-agent or Pagent, but at least you can do it!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `*.pem` file with this format:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
56767567567jhfhfhfghfgghf5464bdf546/56//56565656566fghr656546546546546546546
..
..
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```